Access токен продолжает жить после выхода, drf
Генерирую токены, получаю refresh и access токены. Когда я по /logout передаю refresh токен, то он больше не действует, но access токены, полученные, с помощью этого рефреш токена, продолжает работать, до его срока истечения. Как избавиться от такого поведения, и прекратить работу access токенов? Использую:

Django==5.1.1
djangorestframework==3.15.2
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.3.1
PyJWT==2.9.0

settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    ...
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(hours=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=7),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': '',
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JSON_ENCODER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY': True,
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
    'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(hours=1),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=7),

    'TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainPairSerializer',
    'TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSerializer',
    'TOKEN_VERIFY_SERIALIZER': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenVerifySerializer',
    'TOKEN_BLACKLIST_SERIALIZER': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenBlacklistSerializer',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainSlidingSerializer',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSlidingSerializer',
}

urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenBlacklistView, TokenRefreshView

from .views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('/login', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('/logout', TokenBlacklistView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('/refresh', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]


Никак, jwt специально спроектирован именно таким образом
